# Matrix one-to-one and onto

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the standard matrix

\begin{array} {lcr}
 0 & -2 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & -1 \\
-1 & 2 & 3 \\
 \end{array}

I know that the reduced form is

\begin{array} {lcr}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
 \end{array}

I don't see why this isn't one-to-one and onto. My book makes the claim that it isn't one-to-one but it seems to fit the definition perfectly.

Comment: This is surjective and injective. For example you can show that the kernel is trivial. If so the image has dimension 3 and it's onto.

Comment: I have no clue what you are saying, I am unfamiliar with surjective, injective, kernal, image and 3 dimensions.

Comment: Injective is one to one. Surjective is onto. Kernel is all the vectors in the domain that map to zero. Image is what you call

Comment: @PaulthePirate, once again you take a rather negative attitude. If you **really** have no clue about surjective, injective, kernel ,image, etc., then  you can **not** even dream of trying to do this problem and you should better go back to the basics (high school-college)...unless you expect someone will completely solve this for you.

Comment: @DonAntonio This is not necessarily true. The language may differ and they might not have talked about these concepts. Infective is another word for one to one. Surjective is another word for onto. Image is all the vectors of the form Ax. Kernel is the set of vectors in the domain that map to the zero vector. You don't need the concept of dimension for this problem.

Comment: @Luis, that is necessarily true in this case: I know the OP. It's also *almost* obvious that the OP's command of the language makes him capable enough to **at least** search for the terms in case he didn't know them in english (again, not the case here). Of course, you can check the history of questions asked by any poster...

Comment: Yea obviously he can and SHOULD look up the definitions on his own. I agree with you. But the lack of knowledge of the language does not imply incompetence to do the problem. You might be right in this case.

Comment: I didn't even mention incompetence or anything remotely related to that, @Luis. I mentioned **attitude** ... You are new and you should really know a little more about the history of some people in this site.

Comment: @DonAntonio You are right. I probably misinterpreted your language, I apologise. I did not think of looking up someone's history before answering the question (Honestly, I did not know you could do this...) In any case, Paul, knowing the language, you most certainly can proceed.

Comment: This may be nitpicking, but a matrix cannot be one-to-one. The linear map that is represents can.

Answer (score 2):

Your book must have a typo in it, then. If you don't want to trust your row reduction:

Let $A$ be any matrix. We want to know whether or not $A$ is injective (also known as one-to-one). It turns out that instead of having to check whether or not every element in the range has more than one preimage, i.e. $Ax = Ay \Rightarrow x = y$, we can simply check what gets mapped to the zero vector. This follows from linearity of matrices: we have $Ax = Ay \Leftrightarrow Ax - Ay = 0 \Leftrightarrow A(x - y) = 0$, so some nonzero vector is mapped to zero under $A$ if, and only if, $Ax = Ay$ for some $x \neq y$. The set of vectors that are mapped to zero under $A$ is called the $kernel$ of $A$, written $\text{Ker}(A)$. So an equivalent condition for $A$ being one-to-one is that $Ax = 0 \Rightarrow x = 0$. Let's check this with your matrix. The equation

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -2 & 0\\
1 & 0 & -1\\
-1 & 2 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
\hspace{0.2cm}
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

yields instantly that $y = 0$ and that $x = z$. But then $3z - x = 0 \Rightarrow 2z = 0 \Rightarrow z = 0$ so $x = 0$ too, so indeed that matrix is injective, as its kernel is just the zero vector.

Comment: So my book is wrong for sure? I don't quite follow where you get the 0 vector from.

Comment: Yes, your book is definitely wrong. I elaborated more on the answer to explain injectivity, the kernel, where the $0$ comes from, etc.